# Search and replace with multiple special characters

Tags: substitute

I would like to replace every instance of `...` with the string `\ldots`, but both strings contain special characters. I have tried `:%s/\<...\>/\ldots` but this searches for all three character words and seemingly replaces them with "dots". How can I do this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Which "both strings"?  What do you mean by "special characters"? `%s/\.\.\./\\ldots/g` will replace all groups of three dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not positive as you're a little vague on the details, but I believe the problem stems from the fact that `\l` is not interpreted literally. Use `\\l` to get a literal `\l` in this case.

In a search and replace a `\l` will make the next character lowercase. To avoid this we escape the backslash with another backslash.

The second problem is that `.` in regex stands for any character. So, in fact `\<...\>` will search for any three character word as you've described. As Sato Katusura suggests, use `\.\.\.` to get three dots.

Answer (score 4):

Tumbler41's answer is a great explanation of why your approach doesn't work. Here's another solution:

Use the "magic" flag. This tells vim which characters should be treated as special and which ones should not. If you specify "Nomagic" with `\V`, than only the backslash character will be special.

```
:%s/\V.../\\ldots/g
```

From `:help magic`

```
3. Magic                            */magic*

Some characters in the pattern are taken literally.  They match with the same
character in the text.  When preceded with a backslash however, these
characters get a special meaning.

Other characters have a special meaning without a backslash.  They need to be
preceded with a backslash to match literally.

                            */\v* */\V*
Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"

Use of "\V" means that in the pattern after it only the backslash and the
terminating character (/ or ?) has a special meaning.  "very nomagic"

Examples:
after:      \v       \m       \M         \V       matches
             $       $        $          \$       matches end-of-line
             .       .        \.         \.       matches any character
             *       *        \*         \*       any number of the previous atom
             ~       ~        \~         \~       latest substitute string
             ()      \(\)     \(\)       \(\)     grouping into an atom
             |       \|       \|         \|       separating alternatives
             \a      \a       \a         \a       alphabetic character
             \\      \\       \\         \\       literal backslash
             \.      \.       .          .        literal dot
             \{      {        {          {        literal '{'
             a       a        a          a        literal 'a'
```